# How to restrict multiple selection using ng2-select with same options list

Tags: angularjs, typescript, html-select, angular2-forms

I have used two ng2-select dropdowns one for user share with editing rights and other without editing rights. If one user is selected in either one don't want to show the user in the other dropdown. How can I manipulate the list? Or is there any other better way to achieve this? Adding my HTML snippet for understanding.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="noEditShare">Share with colleagues (no editing rights)</label>
    <ng-select  [multiple]="true"
    [items]="usersList"
    [active]="selectedUsersRead"
    [disabled]="disabled"
    (data)="refreshValueMultiSelect($event)"
    (selected)="selectedMultiSelect($event, 'read_only')"
    (removed)="removedMultiSelect($event, 'read_only')"
    placeholder="No user selected"></ng-select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="editShare">Share with colleagues (editing rights)</label>
    <ng-select  [multiple]="true"
    [items]="usersList"
    [active]="selectedUsersWrite"
    [disabled]="disabled"
    (data)="refreshValueMultiSelect($event)"
    (selected)="selectedMultiSelect($event, 'read_write')"
    (removed)="removedMultiSelect($event, 'read_write')"
    placeholder="No user selected"></ng-select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Manipulating usersList doesn't seem to work.